# Events While scrolling my page

Tags: jquery

now i have a problem, i have an element that i want it to fade in in just one case, and to fade Out in the opposite, but when it comes to fading out, everything is fine, while my element never fade in, and my element shows up only if i refresh my page .. 
Hope you understand and help, Thank you ..

here is my script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).scroll(function () {
    upfonction()
})
})

function upfonction(mydiv) {
var mydiv = $(".slach").offset().top

if(mydiv < 870){
    $(".slach").fadeOut()
   }
   else if(mydiv > 870){
    $(".slach").fadeIn()
   }
   else {
      $(".slach").fadeIn()
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a scroll value as an argument to the function, which requires an argument by your definition definition .

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  upfonction(e.currentTarget.scrollY)
});
```

Or

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  upfonction($(window).scrollTop())
});
```

`var mydiv = $(".slach").offset().top` will always be a constant irrespective of the scroll position.

Comment: No, that is not the problem, and the argument in the function is just a mistake, actually my code is without it, and i pasted the wrong code here Haha xD but i have solved my problem and thank you sir, have a good day